# what does the word " stop" mean when it comes to context of living room?

Tags: word-meaning

I looked it up in Longman Dict, but I couldn't find it.When a landlord is talking about doors, stops and locks, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it means door-stop, a small device installed on floor or wall to stop a door from further rotating, or hitting the wall too hard, upon opening.

You can search door-stop in google for images.